# Steam UI keeps closing and reopening while Steam is still running in background

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, software-installation, gui, steam

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and installed Steam through 'repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam.' The app keeps disappearing and reloading like it just started. At the same time, it remains in the status bar at the top as if it is still running. I can't do anything because the UI constantly disappears and reloads as if I just launched it (back to the promo window and home screen).

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64-bit
- Gnome: 3.36.8
- Windowing System: X11
- Processor: AMD® Phenom(tm) ii x4 830 processor × 4
- Graphics: GeForce GT 730/PCIe/SSE2
- Graphics driver: nvidia-driver-390 (proprietary)

**Here are the instructions I used from another website (https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/):**

Steam for Linux - launcher
The latest release for Ubuntu LTS is available here: steam_latest.deb

This is a launcher/bootstrapper package containing:

the steam-devices udev rules
a minimal version of Steam, enough for the self-update mechanism to download the rest
Installing via apt
Download steam.gpg and copy it to /usr/share/keyrings/steam.gpg, then run:

$ sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam-stable.list <<'EOF'
deb [arch=amd64,i386 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/steam.gpg] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam
deb-src [arch=amd64,i386 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/steam.gpg] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam
EOF
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install 
libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 
libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 
steam-launcher